# How to retrieve the pg_config file from Azure postgresql Database

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, psycopg2

Trying to install a postgresql database which resides on Azure for my python flask application; but the installation of `psycopg2` package requires the *pg_config* file which comes when *postgresql* is installed. So how do I export the *pg_config* file from the postgresql database which also resides on azure? Is *pg_config* all `psycopg2` need for a successful installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the specific `pg_config` from the target database. It's only being used to compile against `libpq`, the client library for PostgreSQL, so you only need the matching PostgreSQL client installed on your local machine.

If you're on Windows I strongly advise you to install a pre-compiled PostgreSQL. You can just install the whole server, it comes with the client libraries.

If you're on Linux, you'll probably need the PostgreSQL -devel or -dev package that matches your PostgreSQL version.